# How Do I Convert DMS to DD in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I am extremely new to python programming and currently carrying out my first project. However, at this moment in time, I have been ground to a complete halt. I have looked at many solutions but none of them seems to work.

I have a Pandas Data frame of latitude and longitude coordinates of 32 boroughs of London in the format of this the coordinates are a mixture of East and West however the Latitude remains the same (North):

0. Barking and Dagenham    51°33′39″N  0°09′21″E
1. Barnet                  51°37′31″N  0°09′06″W
2. Bexley                  51°27′18″N  0°09′02″E
3. Brent                   51°33′32″N  0°16′54″W
4. Bromley                 51°24′14″N  0°01′11″E

I need to format the coordinates so they look like this:

0. Barking and Dagenham    51.560833  0.155833
1. Barnet                  51.625278  -0.151667
2. Bexley                  51.455000  0.150556
3. Brent                   51.558889  -0.281667
4. Bromley                 51.403889  0.019722

I have got this far:

```
pattern = r'(?P<d>[\d\.]+).*?(?P<m>[\d\.]+).*?(?P<s>[\d\.]+)'

dms = df['Latitude'].str.extract(pattern).astype(float)

df['LATITUDE'] = dms['d'] + dms['m'].div(60) + dms['s'].div(3600)

dms = df['Longitude'].str.extract(pattern).astype(float)

df['LONGITUDE'] = dms['d'] + dms['m'].div(60) + dms['s'].div(3600)
```

What I need is to take the directions into consideration.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Following the same pattern you already using, add the regex group to capture the hemisphere letter

```py
...]+).*?(?P<h>[NSWE])
```

Use the `str.extract` but don't convert to float yet. Apply Pandas [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) function to convert the letters to a number, and then apply the conversion to `float`. Change the formula being used to calculate de `latitude` and `longitude` to take the hemisphere directions into consideration as shown below.

```py
pattern = r'(?P<d>[\d\.]+).*?(?P<m>[\d\.]+).*?(?P<s>[\d\.]+).*?(?P<h>[NSWE])'
hemisphere_sig = {'N': 1, 'S': -1, 'E': 1, 'W': -1}

dms = df['Latitude'].str.extract(pattern)
dms['h'] = dms['h'].map(hemisphere_sig)
dms = dms.astype(float)

df['LATITUDE'] = dms['h'] * (dms['d'] + dms['m'].div(60) + dms['s'].div(3600))

dms = df['Longitude'].str.extract(pattern)
dms['h'] = dms['h'].map(hemisphere_sig)
dms = dms.astype(float)

df['LONGITUDE'] = dms['h'] * (dms['d'] + dms['m'].div(60) + dms['s'].div(3600))
print(df)
```

*Output*

```
                                           0    Latitude  Longitude   LATITUDE  LONGITUDE
0  Barking and Dagenham 51°33′39″N 0°09′21″E  51°33′39″N  0°09′21″E  51.560833   0.155833
1                Barnet 51°37′31″N 0°09′06″W  51°37′31″N  0°09′06″W  51.625278  -0.151667
2                Bexley 51°27′18″N 0°09′02″E  51°27′18″N  0°09′02″E  51.455000   0.150556
3                 Brent 51°33′32″N 0°16′54″W  51°33′32″N  0°16′54″W  51.558889  -0.281667
4               Bromley 51°24′14″N 0°01′11″E  51°24′14″N  0°01′11″E  51.403889   0.019722
```